# Estou com uma duvida em relação a regex

Tags: php, regex

Bom, como eu faço pro regex identificar que estou querendo pegar o primeiro fechamento de uma tag ou seja, queria pegar apegar a primeira linha da tag **li** e logo depois queria fazer um foreach para ir capturando linha por linha.

Mas não sei como fazer isso...

Aqui um exemplo do regex na prática: https://regex101.com/r/sM9jW0/1

Comment: Queres apanhar pedaços de HTML? podes mostrar o HTML que tens e o pedaço que queres selecionar? já olhaste para http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php ?

Comment: Haha é você Sergio? Poxa achei que você era brasileiro rsrs, obrigado por responder...

Sim quero pegar pedaços de HTML, segue o link para que você possa ver o que estou tentando fazer: https://regex101.com/r/sM9jW0/1

Comment: Eu tinha visto esse link do regex101, podes dar um exemplo do resultado que queres ter? Ou seja as linhas com que esperas ficar no final.

Comment: vou explicar melhor, é o seguinte estou nesse site: http://www.filmesonlinegratis.net/assistir-a-era-do-gelo-o-big-bang-dublado-online.html estou tentando pegar os player de filmes... no caso eu quero pegar tipo o player 1 -> iframe 1, player 2 -> iframe 2 e assim por diante, sendo assim colocando eles em um foreach para exibir a quantidade de players que o site tem

Comment: Obter HTML por REGEX não é uma boa. O PHP oferece recurso especifico para isso, o `DOMDocument`, veja em http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php. Se você compreende o DOM do Javascript é extremamente fácil usar isto, basicamente arrisco dizer que é "mesma coisa" haha. :)

Comment: Segue o código que estou usando no momento: http://pastebin.com/0nVqxRTp

Comment: @Inkeliz eu até comecei usar o DOMDocument, porem não tive sucesso, na verdade estou com dificuldades para entender o processo do DOM